# RHEL 8 yum - how to remove repos without mirror

Tags: rhel, yum, repository, mirror

I used RHEL 8 for the first time yesterday and I've added all available repos to yum using

```
yum-config-manager --enable \*
```

afterwards I noticed that for many of them there are no mirrors and that the udpate/install process never finishes as long as there are repos without mirrors.

Is there a way to remove all repos from yum automatically for which no mirrors are available?

Else I have to repeatedly type the repo name at the end of each failed yum update attempt to the disable command from the following error

```
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-eus-source-rpms':
  - Status code: 404 for https://cdn.redhat.com/content/eus/rhel8/8/x86_64/baseos/source/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 23.63.144.251)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-eus-source-rpms': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

So is there are way to detect and disable all repos automatically for which there is no mirror available?